# Extract car images without Mask RCNN

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I want to extract car images without using Mask RCNN. I tried a couple of methods but couldn't decide on how to proceed with any of them. I need recommendation on which method would be best and how to go through with it.

**Method 1 - Using XML files and haar cascade classifier**
I was thinking of using xml files to detection and crop car images. The problems I faced were:

- They only detect car in square shapes. I needed car images cropped. So ultimately I ended up with better images of cropped cars. This didn't solve my problem.
- The cropped image didn't detect car as a whole but small parts of it. Maybe due to XML file's config.
  My code:

```
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shaanhk/New-GithubTest/master/cars.xml
import numpy as py
import cv2

car_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('cars.xml')
img = cv2.imread('im1.jpg')
cars = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.1, 1)
for (x,y,w,h) in cars: 
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2) 

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Resulting image:

[image: XML Result Image]

**Method 2 - Using Canny Edge Detection**

I tried to perform canny edge detection for car. It worked to some extent that I managed to reduce edges to mostly car object. But I don't know how to proceed from there.
My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image= cv2.imread('im1.jpg')

imagecopy= np.copy(image)
grayimage= cv2.cvtColor(imagecopy, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
canny= cv2.Canny(grayimage, 300,150)
cv2.imshow('Highway Edge Detection Image', canny)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Resulting Image:

[image: Canny Car Edge]

**Method 3 - Extract car image using color gradients**

On googling I found a method using HSV transformation and then creating a custom mask to extract cars. But I don't know much about this method and have no idea how to go about it. I used the code provided and am posting it below.
Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import cv2
%matplotlib inline

image = mpimg.imread('im1.jpg')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

# HSV channels
h = hsv[:,:,0]
s = hsv[:,:,1]
v = hsv[:,:,2]

background_hue = h[10,10]
lower_hue = np.array([background_hue-10,0,0]) 
upper_hue = np.array([background_hue+10,255,255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_hue, upper_hue)

# Mask the image to let the car show through
masked_image = np.copy(image)

masked_image[mask != 0] = [0, 0, 0]

cv2.imwrite('mask.jpg',masked_image)
# Display it!
plt.imshow(masked_image)
```

Image:

[image: Mask Image]

I'd like to mention, I'm a complete beginner in Computer Vision and am trying to learn by doing some small stuff like these. My code is probably very flawed and hopefully I can work on it on the way. Please feel absolutely free to mention any other method (except Mask RCNN) or any problems with code.

Comment: Your last method is the best. First you should use BGR2HSV, not RGB2HSV as OpenCV cv2.imread() uses that format. That will keep your extracted car as red. Then you should process the threshold mask using morphology to clean it up and contours. Then draw the biggest contour as white on black background. Then use the mask to make the background either completely black or transparent. Make it black for example, using image[mask==0] = (0,0,0)

Comment: why do you not want ro use Mask R-CNN? Generalized object detection is a very difficult task and it's not long since MASK R-CNN has given a quite well working solution.

Comment: Mask R-CNN is instance segmentator. Meaning it produces per pixel annotation. Do you want that? Or you just need a bounding box around each car (=1 label per box)? You should probably stick with a deep CNN network but depending on what exactly you need (as mentioned before) no help can be given.

Comment: Actually, I decided to work with deep learning. I am training a UNet model on car masks so that it can predict mask for any car image. It kind of sounds weird, but I wanted to do what mask rcnn does, without using it.
Of course with we can extract car image using a bounding box, but it would basically be a cropped image containing car. What I wanted was to extract the car itself.